PWA that can read RFID in passports
I'm building a PWA (HTML, JS, PHP) for bouncers, and my customer needs to scan an ID-card or Passport, to verify the identity of the holder. I need to extract the image, date of birth and the name from the RFID-chip.
I do use the NFC-reader through Web NFC in the PWA already for reading other RFID-chips, but I'm not sure how to extract the image from the identification.
Does anyone know if this is even possible? And if so, are the any tutorials/other posts out there that can help me in the right direction?

Not possible with Web NFC, also Web NFC support is poor (Web NFC compatibility)
Web NFC only supports reading the NDEF data format and passports are not stored in the NDEF data format.
You really need an App that can access the Native NFC reader API's, either via Native code or via something like React Native,etc.
To access the e-passport NFC data is complicated, you need to OCR some data from the main passport page to access the data.
Also some hardware does not allow the use of NFC and the Camera at the same time, so you would have to split these operations.

It is not really necessary to scan the OCR area as you need 3 data fields (Passport number, the birthday and the expiration date) as parameters for the access of the passport data. So you can avoid the NFC - Camera problems :-)

Yes a human can OCR (read) the data fields and input them manually ;-), but you could also easily separate theses steps in an App to not try and do both operations concurrently. Especially as when the camera's field of view is wide enough to read the OCR strip it will be out of NFC range.

B.t.w.: I used the NFC TagInfo app (by @Michael Roland, not the NXP one) to read the passport data without scanning or entering the MRZ data (passport number, dates of birth and expire) - how is that possible ? To my knowledge the BAC authentication uses the 3 data fields for "access control" reasons ("BAC"), and I never saw an application that is being able to readout even basic data from the ePassport.

@MichaelFehr That app is too old for me to run, but it does have a activity to enter the MRZ data (are you sure it has not remembered it from before?) but a quick search suggests that it might also be possible to use a 6 digit Card Access Number https://developers.innovatrics.com/digital-onboarding/docs/functionalities/document/nfc-reading/#access-control

Oh, yes. as there is no button real "visible" I did not mention that I could have entered it before. Testing the same with the passport of my wife I got a wife and an "area" to type on and enter the number and dates...
